# How to configure Command line to use the newest PHP version?

Tags: php, command-line, wamp

In command line, if I php-v it returns PHP 5.3.13 however I have updated wamp to 5.4.0

I'm sure this is simple but how do I force command line to use the newest version of PHP

Comment: Put it first on path, use full path or uninstall old version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How Windows responds to commands depends on your environmental variables.
Check the directory given to where the PHP executable is.  Different version, different executable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the directory that has php.exe in you WAMP installation into your PATH. It is usually something like C:\wamp\xampp\php

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows, check in your system PATH if you have the old version linked. Remove it and add the new one